# About usage framework coreData

Tags: ios, core-data

What is the best way to use CoreData:

1 - The first time I load all items from the store in the array, in the future, when I have to get one item (or more,meet certain properties), I just do filtering array (filteredArrayUsingPredicate)

OR

2 - Every time when I need to get the items (one item or several or all items) I load those games all from the repository?

When I am asking what is the best way, I actually mean what is the most efficient and most common way (quickest response time)?

Answer (score 1):

Use MagicalRecord library. It has convienience methods like:
MR_findAll
MR_findFirst
MR_findFirstByAttribute and many, many others.

Comment: but if i do not use third-party libraries&. how better to do?

Comment: it is important for me to understand the whole essence of the work

Comment: You wanted to know best way to use (perhaps simple is the best way at beginning) - understanding is different thing: read the docs, watch WWDC videos about core data best practices and most important is to experiment yourself with features like nested contexts, merging etc.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use data arrays, and don't use 3rd party libraries.

Rather, read up on [`NSFetchedResultsController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and discover how simple and scalable core data can be.